# running "ls -lthr" in terminal

Tags: terminal, ls

Basic question, in terminal, what does the below do?

```
ls -lthr
```

what's the difference between the above and the normal

```
ls -l
```

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to understand that each letter after the `-` is an option.

You can see those options using `ls --help` or man : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html

```
  -l
    use a long listing format

  -t     
    sort by time, newest first; see --time

  -h, --human-readable
    with -l and -s, print sizes like 1K 234M 2G etc.

  -r, --reverse
    reverse order while sorting
```